# Hashtags feature in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am building an Instagram clone and I want to implement this feature.
Suppose a user uploaded an image and its descriptions goes as follows:

```
This is me #HappyTimes #tbh #helloall #blogger #writer
```

I want that all the hashtags automatically convert to links. There should be no separate field for image description and hashtags; the user writes the description and hashtags get converted.

How can I implement this? Currently, I have a model for user, user profile and image. The image will be connected to user via foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm going to assume that by 'converting into links', you mean a single url such as example.com/hashtag, where hashtag would be the content of the URL.

If you want the hashtags to be converted to links as the user types them in, you're going to need javascript. If you want the change to be made on submit, you could also probably do it in python. Essentially, here's what you need to do:

1. Take the content of the input field you are working with. Probably save it as a string.
2. Isolate words that start with a hashtag. In python, I'd probably convert the string into a list, that would be separated by spaces. (use the .split() method on the string.
3. For each string in the list that starts with a hashtag, add in a  [at the beginning, and a](http://example.com/path/hashtag)  at the end. Obviously, you're going to have to decide on your own URL structure. In order to get the actual hashtag text, probably take a slice of the string from [1:]
4. Turn the list back into a string
5. Make sure you allow HTML in the resulting template. Also, make sure you clean the user's input with something like [bleach](https://github.com/mozilla/bleach). I am not responsible if you forget to do this, and your website is hacked by XSS.

This is the easiest way I could think of doing this. You could probably implement this either in python in the save method of the form, or in the view itself, or through javascript.